# JMeter __RandomFromMultipleVars not working

Tags: jmeter

Using JMeter 5.4, I'm trying to use [__RandomFromMultipleVars](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars) function

> The RandomFromMultipleVars function returns a random value based on the variable values provided by Source Variables.

Even from examples from documentation:

> ```
> ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(val)}
> ```
>
> will return a random string based on content of variable val taking into account whether they are multi-value or not

> ```
> ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(val1|val2)}
> ```
>
> will return a random string based on content of variables val1 and val2 taking into account whether they are multi-value or not

> ```
> ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(val1|val2, MYVAR)}
> ```

But I don't get any value and not error in log (`MYVAR` is empty)

What is wrong? can it be used in a specific settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables need to be present (either come from a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or declared via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element)

[image]

[image]

So just make sure that your `varl1` and `val2` variables exist and have their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)